# Config Transformations /Multiple Config files for Class Library Project +.NET

Tags: app-config, transformation, class-library

I have a .NET Class library project and I have App.Config file, I would like to have multiple config files using transformation as per env/criteria. How can I achieve that ? As it's being a class library I am unable to do it, I have done that in the past for Console and Web Applications.  I am using visual studio 2012 and .NET 4.5

Comment: Use this extension https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/579d3a78-3bdd-497c-bc21-aa6e6abbc859

Comment: @SamLeach I have tried that already, looks like it works for only web/console applications. I have Class Library Project

Comment: The example on the link is for a ConsoleApplication. Download the example. There is a class library called "Shared" using config transforms.

Comment: I tried sam,when I click Add Config Transform, it won't create anything..

Comment: Download the example that they link. I tested in VS 2015. Don't have 2012 to test.

Comment: Okay, it worked for me. I was getting a pop-up "GolavanArvaham.ConfigurationTransform.ConfigurationTransformPacakge didnot load correctly"... I applied binding redirect and then it worked for me...

Comment: @SamLeach please post this in answer section, will mark as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/579d3a78-3bdd-497c-bc21-aa6e6abbc859) extension. There is an example to download which should help.